# Change Windows 10 Start Menu Icon

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I want to change the icon in the start menu:

[image: Start Menu Icon]

I'm willing to mess with the Registry, and I am well aware that I should make backups (and do!)

**How will I accomplish this?**

Comment: This cannot be done without third-party software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft has since patched the icon registry key. Gone are the good old easy replacement.

If you are unwilling to install 3rd Party software, then there is no *current* solution to your problem.

---

**Some third party software that will achieve your goal**

[Classic Shell](http://classicshell.net/)

- Pros: Free
- Cons: Classic shell will replace the entire Windows 10 Start Menu.

[Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/)

- Pros: Can do task
- Cons: Costs $5

**Disclaimer**

There may be other software available, but these are the current ones I know of. I do not want to turn this into a software recommendation, but this provides an answer to people who come here looking for a solution.